# America's top general, is this a specific one or one of top generals?

Tags: vocabulary, determiners

> **America's top general** has signalled US troops could engage Islamic State militants on the battlefield, in spite of president Barack Obama's repeated assurance they will not. ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4089098.htm))

From the auxiliary, *has*, I can tell that ‘an American general’ must have told that, as in this sentence of [VOA](http://m.voakorea.com/a/a-35-2005-05-18-voa12-91178734/1292307.html): “*Today, **a top general** in the interior ministry (Ibrahim Khamas) was killed in a drive-by shooting*.” And wondering why do they not use ‘an’ in the sentence, I got this idea: maybe determiner ‘a/an’ could be dropped when the NP explicitly denote that it is any single person. 
But after I found out that ‘*top general*’ may be the top single one general who presides the general staffs, I got perplexed. Why isn’t there ‘*an*’ in the example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When can an article be omitted?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/when-can-an-article-be-omitted)

Comment: Just to be clear, no article was omitted from this phrase.  There is no ellipsis here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***America's*** is a genitive noun phrase in determiner position.  Genitive NPs in determiner position are definite.  The determiner slot is full and adding ***an*** would be ungrammatical.

In this context, there is only one top general.  As I explained above, ****an America's top general*** would be ungrammatical, so to express that this is only one of several top generals, you would have to write ***one of America's top generals***.