# Imperative form of "prove"

Tags: verb-forms

What is the imperative form of the verb to prove?

The English dictionaries do not list up the imperative form.

Comment: Most all English Imperative forms are merely the verb with no subject.

Comment: After searching for "prove imperative", I found the answer on www.verbix.com: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/prove.html.

Comment: Thank you very much, ColleenV. I have been looking for an online English verb conjugator, apparently not well enough! I appreciate you sharing the link!

Comment: Er, you do realize that the verb form used in an imperative is the same verb form that is used by a dictionary for that entry? That is, the lexical base of the verb (e.g. ***be***) is used for that verb's entry in a dictionary, and it is also used for the imperative.

Comment: F.E., thank you. I probably learned that once way back, but no, I did not remember this. You saved me from a lot of work the next time I need an imperative form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "prove", as in

> For homework, prove this theorem.

or

> You're wrong!
>
> > Oh, yeah?  Prove it!

Comment: Why not "for THE homework"?

Comment: @Anixx: I suppose there are various phrases that could be acceptable: “For your homework”, “For tonight’s homework”, “This homework problem”, etc. I would tend not to use “the” because I’m looking at “homework” as a collective/uncountable noun. I would not use “the” in “For exercise, run up and down the stairs” or “For practice, recite your speech in an empty room.” See [When can an article be omitted?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/when-can-an-article-be-omitted)